# rails check_box not passing false when unchecked

Tags: ruby-on-rails, checkbox, devise

I'm still having trouble with this annoying `check_box` stuff in Ruby on Rails. I'm working on authorization now, and I have a User class to do so. I've installed and set up Devise to do the grunt work. The User has a `is_teacher` variable to indicate whether or not that user is a Teacher, and therefore allowed to do more. The problem is that the `check_box`es are not passing in false for that variable when the check box is unchecked. The sign up view is the simplest, so I'll post that:

```
<h2>Sign up</h2>

<%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
  <%= devise_error_messages! %>

  <div><%= f.label :email %><br />
  <%= f.email_field :email, :autofocus => true %></div>

  <div><%= f.label :password %><br />
  <%= f.password_field :password %></div>

  <div><%= f.label :password_confirmation %><br />
  <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %></div>

  <div><%= f.check_box :is_teacher %> <%= f.label :is_teacher, "I am a Teacher" %></div>

  <div><%= f.submit "Sign up" %></div>
<% end %>

<%= render "devise/shared/links" %>
```

As I understand it, the `f.check_box :is_teacher` should properly update the `is_teacher` variable. It does so when I check the box (that is, the User is then granted Teacher permissions). However, when I uncheck the box, or leave it unchecked, it gives me an error saying that the `is_teacher` variable cannot be blank. Any ideas?

Comment: How about the gotcha in Rails' documentation? http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-check_box

Comment: Is the `is_teacher` field on the model a Boolean? Are you using the default Devise controller or are you overriding it?

Comment: I did consider the "gotcha" in the Rails' documentation. Since I'm using f.check_box instead of check_box_tag, it should pass the proper hidden_value by default.

`is_teacher` is indeed a Boolean in the database, and I am using the default Devise controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what happened, but it seems to be working now.

I suspect part of my problem may have been my attempt at a solution. When I noticed the `is_teacher` variable wasn't being updated when I unchecked the box, I added a line to the user.rb file that explicitly validated that a value was being given: `validates is_teacher, presence:true` Sadly, I think this backfired on me and failed even when the given value was "falsey", which the view would have been able to use with no problem.

In any case, now that I've removed that validation, it all works perfectly fine. I just wish I knew where my original bug was. Thank you all for helping out! :D

Answer (score 1):

I was going to write this as a comment, but it'll be easier to read here:

HTML forms don't send "false" values for unchecked check boxes - they only send checked values. I may be wrong, but if you perform a `.serialize()` function on the form's data, you'll only get the `checked` values, which are then passed to the controller

To accommodate this, you'll have to set the `is_teacher` column to `boolean` in your db. Reason being if you don't send true, it will default to `false` (0), allowing you to neglect sending the `false` value